# How to stop Evolution from restoring deleted calendar events?

Tags: 20.04, evolution, calendar

I have an event that was created by someone else and sent to *three separate calendars* (two Google and one from another provider), so it appears three times on my Evolution calendar display. This is driving me nuts, so I want to delete two of them.

If I right-click on the duplicate events and select "Delete Appointment," they go away. But then they come back a few minutes later. This is true both for a Google calendar and one from another provider.

I have noticed this in other contexts too, where if I delete a single instance of a recurring event created by someone else it will reappear a few minutes later.

Why, why, why? How can I get this to stop?

Comment: Seems this is a question about Evolution not Ubuntu. Maybe try and get some help from that apps team.